# Access TextView in Layout from Fragment

Tags: android

I'm admittedly quite new to Android development and Java in general, having some problems with something I've seen a ton of other people search for as well, but the other solutions don't seem to be doing it for me.  I had this exact code working in another file, copied it to a different program (switching from NavigationDrawer to NavigationView) and now the Fragment gives me a NullPointerException when it tries to access the TextView.

As near as I can tell I've defined the view before trying to call `findViewById`.  I'm absolutely certain that the problem is in the method `show_life1_total()` with the line

```
TextView life1_total = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.life1_total);
```

but I can't figure out what's wrong with that line because it worked perfectly in a different file.  Any help would be most appreciated.

Alternately, if there's some other way I'm supposed to be handling buttons and views in fragments, please enlighten me.  They were really easy in activities, but the NavigationView forces me to use fragments, and setting up `onClickListeners` for every single button I intend to use in a fragment looks like it's going to be a gigantic amount of what should be unnecessary work.  Maybe I'm missing something obvious.

Here's my Fragment

```
package com.android4dev.navigationview;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.annotation.Nullable;
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.TextView;

/**
 * Created by Admin on 04-06-2015.
 */
public class GameFragment extends Fragment implements View.OnClickListener{

    public static Integer nlife1Total=20;
    public static Integer nlife2Total=20;
    View view;
    Button life1_minus;
    Button life1_plus;
    Button life2_minus;
    Button life2_plus;

    @Nullable
    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_life_counter,container,false);

        life1_minus = (Button) view.findViewById(R.id.life1_minus);
        life1_minus.setOnClickListener(this);

        life1_plus = (Button) view.findViewById(R.id.life1_plus);
        life1_plus.setOnClickListener(this);

        life2_minus = (Button) view.findViewById(R.id.life2_minus);
        life2_minus.setOnClickListener(this);

        life2_plus = (Button) view.findViewById(R.id.life2_plus);
        life2_plus.setOnClickListener(this);

        show_life1_total();
        show_life2_total();

        return view;
    }

    public void startNewGame()
    {
        nlife1Total=20;
        nlife2Total=20;
        //show_life1_total();
        //show_life2_total();
    }

    public void show_life1_total() {
        TextView life1_total = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.life1_total);
        String display_life1_total = String.valueOf(nlife1Total);
        life1_total.setText(display_life1_total);
    }


    public void show_life2_total() {
        TextView life2_total = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.life2_total);
        String display_life2_total = String.valueOf(nlife2Total);
        life2_total.setText(display_life2_total);
    }

    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        switch(v.getId()){
            case R.id.life1_minus:
                nlife1Total--;
                show_life1_total();
                break;
            case R.id.life1_plus:
                nlife1Total++;
                show_life1_total();
                break;
            case R.id.life2_minus:
                nlife2Total--;
                show_life2_total();
                break;
            case R.id.life2_plus:
                nlife2Total++;
                show_life2_total();
                break;
        }
    }
}
```

The relevant view from the xml file (this is in fragment_life_counter.xml)

```
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/life1_total"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:textSize="140sp"
        android:text="@string/life1_total"
        android:fontFamily="sans-serif-thin"
        android:textColor="@color/life_color"
        android:background="@drawable/backdrop_ubr_grixis" />
```

Along with the logcat

```
08-27 22:17:46.103  18943-18943/com.android4dev.navigationview E/AndroidRuntime﹕ FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    Process: com.android4dev.navigationview, PID: 18943
    java.lang.NullPointerException
            at com.android4dev.navigationview.GameFragment.show_life1_total(GameFragment.java:69)
            at com.android4dev.navigationview.GameFragment.onCreateView(GameFragment.java:54)
            at android.support.v4.app.Fragment.performCreateView(Fragment.java:1962)
            at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:1016)
            at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:1197)
            at android.support.v4.app.BackStackRecord.run(BackStackRecord.java:738)
            at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.execPendingActions(FragmentManager.java:1562)
            at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl$1.run(FragmentManager.java:483)
            at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:733)
            at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
            at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:157)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5293)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1265)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1081)
            at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have declared a View in the method that will act as a local varibale and it will be destroyed. Make it a global or you have already declared a global View varibale initailize it.

Follow this-

Instead of--

```
 public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_life_counter,container,false);
```

remove the View because you have already declared it on top of the class.

make it like this--

```
 public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
     view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_life_counter,container,false);
```

remember you are trying to access a view object in the show_life1_total()  method which is not initialized.

I hope this would help you.

Comment: Perfect, thanks so much!  I knew I had declared it globally so show_life1_total() could find it, I just missed that the "View" at the beginning of that line was declaring it again locally and not using the global one.  Appreciate the help!

Comment: Accepted now.  It made me wait 5 minutes before it would allow me to accept.